# Database with upgradable accounts

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm making a website that having 2 type of roles: Customer and Merchant.
Customers can only buy products on he website.
Merchant can sell and buy products on the same account.
Users can make their account from Customer to Merchant by upgrading it.
This is how I design the tables. Is it a good to make it this way ?

```
table account(
  account_id primary key,
  username,
  password,
  isMerchant bool,
)
table Customer(
  account_id foreign key account(account_id),
  name,
  gender,
  phone,
  email,
  ...etc
)
table Merchant(
  account_id foreign key account(account_id),
  shop's name,
  ...etc
)
```

Oh, while writing tables, I think I could add a primary key to Customer table and let Merchant table has a foreign key from the Customer table.

```
table account(
  account_id primary key,
  username,
  password,
  isMerchant bool,
)
table Customer(
  customer_id primary key,
  account_id foreign key account(account_id),
  name,
  gender,
  phone,
  email,
  ...etc
)
table Merchant(
  customer_id foreign key customer(customer_id),
  shop's name,
  ...etc
)
```

Comment: I'd advise against this approach. There should be many Users (which, by default, act as a customer). There should be many Merchants. Users should be associated with merchants, with a flag for whether they're an admin (or some other role - you may need different levels).

Comment: So how could I design it. Sorry, i'm a bit new to database, this is one of my school project.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't think you're understanding his design -- a merchant is a type of customer, with additional privileges and information. It's not a many-to-many or many-to-one relationship.

Comment: @Barmar In my experience, it's highly likely that a "merchant" would sometimes need more than one user attached to it - multiple employees, assistants/secretaries, temp workers, etc. Better to design it with that in mind than to lock in an inflexible setup that's not gonna scale.

Comment: @ceejayoz That seems to be a separate issue, there needs to be another table of users who manage the merchant accounts. This is more like Ebay -- there are customers who just buy things, and merchants who buy and sell things. A customer can upgrade to a merchant account.

Comment: @Barmar I'm making a small website which is similar to what you said (Sorry, I don't use eBay so I don't know how it work). If a customer want to sell things, they can upgrade their account and do it. They don't need to create a new account.

Comment: Actually, eBay doesn't work that way, either. I think anyone can sell things. I was just trying to help @ceejayoz understand the relationship between customers and merchants, and it's not the same as between employees and merchants.